# Match multiple criteria inside an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following:

```
    offers: [
        {user: 'jon', price: 200, selected: false}, 
        {user: 'ted', price: 100, selected: true}
    ]
```

I am trying to do a match that will get all offer objects where user is ted and selected is true.

I tried the following:

```
$match: {
    "offers.user": "ted"
    "offers.selected": true
}
```

But this will give me the document if there is a ted and a selected true inside the array and not necessary that combination inside the same object.

Comment: Google search: ["mongodb match array by multiple conditions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+match+array+by+multiple+conditions) show's the linked duplicate within the third result from the top ( a couple more before it also using `$elemMatch`, but newer posts ) and the MongoDB Documentation - [Query an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#specify-multiple-conditions-for-array-elements) and it's section of documentation saying exactly the same thing. I suggest reading that section and the entire [MongoDB CRUD Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query operator to match multiple criteria inside an array

```
{ "$match": {
  "offers": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "user": "ted"
      "selected": true
    }
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want mongoose `elemMatch` function for your case.

```
query.elemMatch('comment', { author: 'autobot', votes: {$gte: 5}})
```

See the docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch):